# Authorize Google Script through HTML Webpage

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a website setup that when a button is clicked it will send a request to the Google Script `doPost` Method. I would like to authenticate on behalf of the user accessing the web application when the button is clicked.

The issue I am running into now is that when I call an ajax POST request it does not ask the user to login. If I change the script so that it can be run by anyone, even anonymous, it will run on behalf of a single user which I am trying to avoid.

Any insight on how to allow the user to login during a POST request would be helpful.

My code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function runme(){
        console.log("I was run");
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTOW4PH_hSqi41B66UVdBFZ7g1r5RndYu8dhXZuGKXoEtMx6Dv/exec',
          data: $("#workPLZ").serialize(),
          success: alert($("#workPLZ").serialize())
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="runme()"> Click Me </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this website is not a .gs app using HtmlService, correct?

Comment: What Google Apps Services use your web app?

Comment: No Bryan this is just a html webpage.

Ruben my apps script uses the following services:
URL Fetch
Documents
MailApp